I am calculating the sum and signed overflow on the addition of two signed numbers, but the overflow is not true in some cases. Can anyone correct it?
module top_module (
    input [7:0] a,
    input [7:0] b,
    output reg [7:0] s,
    output reg overflow
);

    always @* begin
        {overflow, s} = a + b;
    end

endmodule


I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE

let's see what it does when you run some test vectors through it

The title say two signed numbers, but I don’t see the signed keyword used anywhere in the code therefore it is performing unsigned addition

@Andyaka Arguably, Verilog is very much EE. Fair chance someone on SO would try and kick that ball our way anyway, thinking similarly.

The bit you are calling overflow is actually the carry bit from the addition. It is equivalent to "overflow" only when adding unsigned numbers. When adding signed numbers, an overflow condition occurs when the sign bit of the result and the carry bit do not match.
For example, when adding two positive numbers such as 01000000 + 01000000 = (0)10000000 (+64 + +64 = +128), the result can't be correctly represented as a signed 8-bit number — the sign has flipped, but there was no carry — overflow.
The same thing happens with negative numbers. 10000001 + 10000001 = (1)00000010 (-127 + -127 = -254). Again, the sign of the result has flipped to 0, but now there is a carry — overflow.
In all non-overflow cases, the sign bit and the carry bit will have the same value.
